# Split large PDF file into single PDF's with python

Tags: python, pdf, pypdf

I'm trying to split a large PDF file per page from page 5000 to 6000. The PDF files has 7000 pages with text and images and is 250MB big. The python code I have written is working for smaller PDF files.

I'm receiving the following errors:
First error is `RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded`.

After setting `sys.setrecursionlimit(9999)` I'm getting the following error `Process finished with exit code -1073741571 (0xC00000FD)`. The PDF file has been written to my output folder but is corrupt and 0kb big. Increasing the recursion limit doesn't help either.

What could I do? Compress the PDF file and then split?

This is my code:

```
pdf_file = open(path,'rb')
    pdf_reader = PdfFileReader(pdf_file)
    pageNumbers = pdf_reader.getNumPages()

    output = PdfFileWriter()

    #this is just to test if it works for 1 page
    output.addPage(pdf_reader.getPage(5854))

    with open("output_path" + "document-output.pdf", "wb") as f:
        output.write(f)
```

Comment: Could you share the file?

Answer (score 0):

Sharing what worked for me. I have used the package `wand` in order to split this PDF file of 7000 pages. [wand package](http://docs.wand-py.org/en/0.4.1/index.html)

```
from wand.image import Image
# Converting #page into JPG
with Image(filename="C:/Users/Name/Documents/PDFfile.pdf[5950]", resolution= 300) as img:
     img.save(filename="C:/Users/Name/Documents/temp1.jpg")
```